# How to create unique index case insensitive at entity framework core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-2.1

I use npqsql 4+ and efcore 2.1+, how I can create unique invariant case insensetive constraint on field?

The following construction doesn't work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasAlternateKey(city => city.Name.ToUpperInvariant());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way to create an index with a specific collation using the Npgsql driver. The only PostgreSQL specific configuration that can be done on an index is to set the method using the `ForNpgsqlHasMethod` extension. You have 
a couple of options:

1. Create/modify the index with some SQL, perhaps as part of a migration
2. Go an request the feature on the [official Github project](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL), or even write your own and submit a pull request!

Answer (score 0):

Change to always save the City Name as uppercase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).